# What's the difference these two?

Tags: difference

1. everything feels so right
2. everything seems so right

I don't know what kind of different nuances.
what's the difference between these two?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Everything feels so right" emphasizes how the speaker *feels* - in other words, what their emotional response is to the person, thing or situation in question. In this case, whatever "right" means in context, the speaker's inner voice is telling them that everything feels right.

For example - "I'm finally doing what I've always wanted to do in life. All my previous jobs felt like a chore. Now, *everything feels so right*."

"Everything seems so right" is a bit of an odd sentence, especially because of the "so". If something really is "*so* right", then it probably doesn't just *seem* that way, unless the speaker is being sarcastic. I can't say it's the only possible interpretation, though.

For example - "Everyone smiles at the office and people are very polite to each other. Everything seems so right, but I know they say nasty things behind each other's back."

A closely related sentence - "Everything seems right." (without the "so") - just means that upon inspection, things look good. It's more of a neutral statement.

Comment: Thanks a lot :）